# Android Allocation Tracker understanding with Mapview

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-mapview

I am trying to optimize my app which is extensively using Mapview i.e. lots of ItemizedOverlay. While trying to see an app on allocation tracker after using an app for some time I am getting below view.

Few other information,

1. App is extending MapActivity. App is having fix orientation.
2. App is not opening any other activity (activity back and forth is not
   happening).
3. Map is showing correctly on the activity.
4. I have seen multiple post on memory management, seen this [Google IO video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) as well but could not address this problem.
5. App is running on ICS Tab.

[image]

My questions are,

1. Please see the Allocation in column and **android_map_conflict..** value, does it suggest that it is the case of MapView + key conflict? What should be work around in such case?
2. Size of the memory allocation under **android_map_conflict...** is keep on increasing. any work around or higher level suggestion? I know it might not needed, but any forceful GC would work? At which place?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I full understand the output of allocation tracker, but I believe it only refletcts the allocated memory, which can later be released and recovered by the GC. So, if you don't have a memory leak (a object that stills referencerd longer then needed) the allocated memory will be returned to free memory.

If you are experiencing issues with memory leak, they may be coming from somewhere else as well. I suggest that you install the MAT as shown in the video you refer. I've done so, using the version Eclipse plug-in, and it worked like a charm. I found the leak in a couple of minutes (after spending a couple of hours, trying to understand how MAT should be used :-) )

good luck